# C programming in Ubuntu SnappyCore

Tags: c, ubuntu-core

I recently downloaded ubuntu snappycore OS. I wonder if i can install a GNU compiler for developing C applications. If I can, how do I do it?

Comment: What is  "ubuntu snappycore OS"?

Comment: Ubuntu Core is an new rendition of Ubuntu that is geared for the Internet of Things. Use the link given below to know more  

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu Core](http://www.ubuntu.com/internet-of-things) is an new rendition of Ubuntu that is geared for the Internet of Things. You should begin by reviewing the documentation on what all it entails [here](http://snapcraft.io/). This will serve as a good starting point and help explain how to develop C application snaps and consume them within the system.

Comment: Thank you, But I got the answers for my question.